# VSCode - Open new terminal window in vsc

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code

Is there any way to open a new terminal window within vscode and run code in it?

Answer (score 2):

Click on "+" button marked with red color

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also go to the View menu and select Terminal. It will open a terminal window under your editor window.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use the command " Ctrl + ` " and it will open a new terminal.